# laravel route calling wrong controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am having an issue where a route is referencing the wrong controller.

Routes:

```
//Event Routes
Route::get('/event/register/thankyou', function(){return view('pages.events.thanks');})->name('event-thanks');
Route::get('/event/waitlist/confirmation', function(){return view('pages.events.waitlist-confirmation');})->name('event-waitlist-confirmation');
Route::get('/event/register/{eventId}/{price}', 'EventController@registerPage')->name('event-register-page')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/event/register/{eventId}', 'EventController@register')->name('event-register')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/event/waitlist/{eventId}', 'EventController@joinWaitlist')->name('event-join-waitlist')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/event/{eventId}/{eventName?}', 'PageControllers@event')->where('eventId', '[0-9]+')->name('event');
Route::get('/regionalevents', 'EventController@regionalEvents')->name('events-regional');
```

On a blade template, I have this button:

```
<a class="btn btn-theme-colored " href="/event/waitlist/{{ $event->id }}">Join Now!</a>
```

For whatever reason, even with the 'where' definer in the /event/{eventId} route - I'm still getting this error when I click the button:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

If I take the 'where' definer out - I get this error:

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object at PageControllers->event('waitlist', '1002')
```

Essentially, it's calling the event function on PageControllers instead of the joinWaitlist function on the EventController.

I've tried reordering the routes, but it's not working either.

On the PageControllers event function, I put a 'dd($eventId);' and when this is the URL: http://localhost:8000/event/waitlist/1002 - it returns "waitlist"

Is there something I'm just straight up missing? I'm completely stuck at this point. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `Route::post('/event/waitlist/{eventId}', 'EventController@joinWaitlist')->name('event-join-waitlist')->middleware('auth');
` is a post request.. change it to get

Answer (score 3):

you are trying route `/event/waitlist/{eventId}` which is `POST` method in anchor tag, which send `GET` method. Also instead of calling static url in blade, use name as below:

```
Route::get('/event/waitlist/{eventId}', 'EventController@joinWaitlist')->name('event-join-waitlist')->middleware('auth');
```

in blade

```
<a class="btn btn-theme-colored " href="{{ route('event-join-waitlist', [$event->id]) }}">Join Now!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to `get` to make it work:

```
Route::get('/event/waitlist/{eventId}'
```

Instead of:

```
Route::post('/event/waitlist/{eventId}'
```

Because you're sending a GET request when you're using `a href` link.